# Django. Как отменить удаление модели в зависимости от условия?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-orm

Переопределив метод `clean` у модели можно задавать кастомные правила валидации данных и если какие-то данные неверны - бросить `ValidationError` с описанием ошибки. Если все это происходит в админке - пользователь увидит красную рамку и сообщение об ошибке.

Но у меня другая задача - в зависимости от условия я должен дать / не дать удалить модель и если модель не может быть удалена - вывести сообщение об ошибке. Например:

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    if not some_func_result():
        raise ValidationError('Запись не может быть удалена')
    else:
        super().delete(using, keep_parents)
```

Однако, исключение покажет дебаггер, а на продакшене будет 500 ошибка.

Можно так:

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    if not some_func_result():
        return 
    else:
        super().delete(using, keep_parents)
```

Но это жесть. Не удалит, покажет, что удалил. Введет в других местах в заблуждение. Есть варианты?

Answer (score 1):

Можно реализовать свой метод удаления объектов из админки и заменить его старым. Можно показать сообщение пользователю к примеру из [ответа на похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471909/django-model-delete-not-triggered):

```
from photoblog.models import PhotoBlogEntry
from django.contrib import admin    

class PhotoBlogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions=['really_delete_selected']

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(PhotoBlogEntryAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def really_delete_selected(self, request, queryset):
        for obj in queryset:
            obj.delete()

        if queryset.count() == 1:
            message_bit = "1 photoblog entry was"
        else:
            message_bit = "%s photoblog entries were" % queryset.count()
        self.message_user(request, "%s successfully deleted." % message_bit)
    really_delete_selected.short_description = "Delete selected entries"

admin.site.register(PhotoBlogEntry, PhotoBlogEntryAdmin)
```